# Transfer function Laplace circuit

Tags: transfer-function

I found the transfer function of a circuit, however I am not sure if I should simplify it further (by factoring out the 10). Which one of these should I consider as my final answer?

$$V_C(s)=\frac{900s+9030}{15s^2+150s+10}$$

$$V_C(s)=\frac{90s+903}{1.5s^2+15s+1}$$

Comment: Divide your first TF through by 15. You can then obtain \$\zeta\$ and \$\omega_n\$ easily from the denominator

Answer (score 6):

You should always factor your transfer functions formulas in a *low-entropy* form, meaning you can read the expression and infer poles, zeroes and gain/attenuation if any. For instance, in your case, you should have a leading term which is the gain of your system for \$s=0\$:

\$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{Q\omega_0}+(\frac{s}{\omega_0})^2}\$

Applied to your example, I would write:

\$V_c(s)=903\cdot \frac{1+0.09967\cdot s}{1+s\cdot 15+s^2\cdot 1.5}\$

The term 0.09967 has a dimension of time and its inverse is the zero. Then by simple identification between the coefficients in the denominator and those of the normalized form I gave, you can calculate the quality factor \$Q\$ and the resonant frequency \$\omega_0\$. You can have a look at my [APEC 2016](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202016.pdf) seminar for an introduction to transfer functions.

Comment: Verbal Kint, I sent you an email on your wanadoo email address, about your book in French. Did you receive it? Vincent Petit

Comment: @Vincent, hello, not that I recall? Please send it again.

Comment: Hello, I have sent a new e-mail: first letter of your first name followed by your last name @wanadoo.fr (see your spam ?)